# Using overridden toString method on a returned sorted ArrayList won't account for newline characters

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I have an event class which has information about events like name, location, ticket price etc.
I also have a calendar class whose only instance variable is an ArrayList of the events that get added to it.

My toString method:

```
public String toString() {
    String s = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < calendar.size(); i++) {
        s = s + "\nEvent Name: " + calendar.get(i).getEventName() + " || Event Venue: "
                + calendar.get(i).getEventVenue() + " || Date: " + calendar.get(i).getDate() + " || Tickets Sold: "
                + calendar.get(i).getTicketsSold() + " || Ticket Price: " + calendar.get(i).getTicketPrice()
                + " || Overhead: " + calendar.get(i).getOverhead();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Main method:

```
public class EventTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Event e1 = new Event("Birthday", "Hotel", "2020-04-12", 100, 100, 1000);
        Event e2 = new Event("Easter", "Park", "2020-07-28", 200, 200, 2000);
        Event e3 = new Event("Christmas", "Garage", "2020-03-28", 300, 300, 3000);
        TRAPSCalendar tpc = new TRAPSCalendar();

        tpc.add(e1);
        tpc.add(e2);
        tpc.add(e3);

        System.out.println(tpc.toString());
        System.out.println(tpc.sortByDate().toString());
    }

}
```

It works as intended when I simply use it on the calendar object after adding the events:

Output of first print:

> Event Name: Birthday || Event Venue: Hotel || Date: 2020-04-12 || Tickets Sold: 100 || Ticket Price: 100 || Overhead: 1000
>   Event Name: Easter || Event Venue: Park || Date: 2020-07-28 || Tickets Sold: 200 || Ticket Price: 200 || Overhead: 2000
>   Event Name: Christmas || Event Venue: Garage || Date: 2020-03-28 || Tickets Sold: 300 || Ticket Price: 300 || Overhead: 3000

The problem is when I use one of my sort methods on the ArrayList and then use the toString() method on the sorted returned ArrayList. It won't put the new lines in so I end up with one long line of output for the sorted events that for some reason is encased in brackets.

Output of second print:

> [Name: Christmas || Venue: Garage || Date: 2020-03-28 || Tickets Sold: 300 || Ticket Price: 300 || Overhead: 3000, Name: Birthday || Venue: Hotel || Date: 2020-04-12 || Tickets Sold: 100 || Ticket Price: 100 || Overhead: 1000, Name: Easter || Venue: Park || Date: 2020-07-28 || Tickets Sold: 200 || Ticket Price: 200 || Overhead: 2000]

I'm going to have to create a GUI to display the list of events so its important each will be displayed on a new line after sorting. Also the original order of the list needs to be maintained separately from the sorted version that will be able to be displayed.

Comment: please show the `sortByDate` signature

Comment: `toString()` is not the appropriate tool for a GUI formatter; you'll need a distinct "view" component whose sole task is to format these objects for display.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that `sortByDate` method does not return the `TRAPSCalendar` type (so the `this` reference) but instead returns the sorted `Collection`. So your second `toString` is not called on your calendar but instead on the sorted collection itself. This is why you got this result (with brackets).

Solutions :

```java
 System.out.println(tpc.toString());
 tpc.sortByDate();
 System.out.println(tpc.toString());
```

or modify `sortByDate`by returning the current calendar object (`return this`) instead of the sorted collection.